# length between primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a question, if there is an arbitrary length between primes and there are infinite primes, does that mean there are all possible values of  gaps between primes. At least all even gaps, as primes are mainly odd.

Comment: can't imagine this is known

Comment: This is an open problem, sometimes known as [Polignac's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture#:~:text=In%20number%20theory%2C%20Polignac's%20conjecture,prime%20numbers%20with%20difference%20n.)  Well, that's the conjecture that each even number occurs infinitely often as a prime gap.  I don't know if the question about at least one occurrence has a name.

Comment: @ lulu thank you for your answer

Comment: It's an interesting one. We know that there is no upper limit on the side of a prime gap (this is usually shown via factorials), but we don't know if the sequence checks every box along the way.